# AWS IoT Device SDK for Python without CA certificate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Is it possible to connect to MQTT over websockets via the AWS IoT Device SDK for Python without a CA certificate, using AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key instead? I have it working that way within a javascript app and a java app, I'm wondering if it's possible from Python as well?

```
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient

clientId = "my-client-id"
clientEndpoint = "my-client-endpoint"
accessKeyId = "my-access-key-id"
secretAccessKey = "my-secret-access-key"

myAWSIoTMQTTClient = AWSIoTMQTTClient(clientId, useWebsocket=True)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(clientEndpoint, 443)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureIAMCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.connect()
```

The connection times out. It may be because my router does not allow IPv6 ([read here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/issues/104#issuecomment-363632519)). I tried [this work around](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/issues/34#issuecomment-281999731), but it still is not working, since it seems to need a CA cert.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible?

Comment: It is possible to connect using WSS and IAM credentials.

Comment: @cementblocks - without having a CA cert?

Comment: Correct, no certificate is needed when you do MQTT over WSS using IAM credentials. This is how you would use MQTT in the browser, but it also works in python.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like you need the AWS Iot root CA certificate, my mistake, though it's not clear why.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have a similar thing working in the browser without the root CA certificate and that works fine, so I was hoping take the same route with my python application. Good to know that is probably not the case.

Comment: Why not just include the root ca in your application?

Comment: I'm trying to do that now. I'm new to certification stuff - is the root ca something I create from my personal account? Or something that I download (or copy/paste) from the AWS server authentication section - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-device-certs.html

Comment: Yes, you would just download/copy from the AWS server auth section.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working either. It fails on the ssl.wrap_socket call, both with or without websockets (with the root ca for both, using AWS keys for websockets and the private key and certificate for non-websocket). My policy is basically allow anything. Any other thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: @cementblocks - I created a new question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842954/awsiotpythonsdk-connection-websocket-handshake-error - with my new problem. If you wanted to comment that the root CA is required for the python sdk, I can mark it as the correct response (I'm new to stackoverflow, so if there's a way to accept one of your comments from above, I can do that instead)